# Problem with button template in wpf..?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am very new to wpf. I want to display an Image and a textblock in buttoncontrol. Hence I created a template and binded image to source and textblock to name.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,-96,-21">
            <Grid>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,8" Width="34" Source="{Binding Source}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="46,8,8,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" Foreground="Black"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1_BeginStoryboard"/>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Then I applied this template to the button. And I tried to add content via window loading event.

```
btnAddGropu.Content = new ToolButton() { Source = "Icons/add.png", Name = "Add Group" };
```

The ToolButton class

```
class ToolButton
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I executed the program with excitement and I didn't get button at all...!!!
So whats the problem..? How I can use this template..?

Thank you 
In advance

Comment: How didi you "applied this template to the button"? Where's the actual XAML code of your control that contains the button?

Comment: <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate1}"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have set your button with the control template as below...

```
    <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate1}"/>
```

The **fix for you problem** is to set `DataContext` of the button and not its `Content`.

```
     btnAddGropu.DataContext
       = new ToolButton() { Source = "Icons/add.png", Name = "Add Group" };
```

Although I must insist you change your way of displaying text and image via a `ControlTemplate` that always expects a "specific" DataContext i.e. `ToolButton`.

Control Templates and Data Binding, DataTemplates and User action effects are never to be mixed together.

:-)

Comment: Yes I set the template like you said before.But I didn't set the data context.That works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like this:

```
<Button>
  <StackPanel>
    <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" Fill="Blue"/>
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">Button</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

[MSDN](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-556/ms.help?product=VS&productVersion=100&method=f1&query=System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content%00VS.XamlEditor&locale=en-US&category=TargetFrameworkMoniker:.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)

you can replace the StackPanel with a Grid or DockPanel and embed any controls you want in this container.

Comment: The above will not work if I apply the template. Or you wanted me to remove the template and design with single button if that I know it will work.

Comment: you don't need any template setting for that.

Comment: If you need to have a TextBlock and image within your button then this is the simplest solution, but if you need to have an image with TextBlock that work like a button then you must use Template or ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to correctly handle the customization of a standard control you have to use [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx), which has a `Style` of the button you want.

For example, look here: [Example](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html)

Comment: But How can I display an Image and related text at same time.

Comment: You apply a Style to ContentPresenter, inside that style you define a controls you want. Look Example provided. I did something like that years ago and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set this template to your button? You must set it, because you gave your `ControlTemplate` a name, which makes it explicit. Without a name it would be implicit, thus it will be used automatically.

so

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate1}"/>
```

There are a couple more things in your example i want to point out. You set in your button the `Content` to an instance of your class `ToolButton` which is fine. This class is obviously not a WPF ui control, thus you must tell WPF what to do with it. Thats a `DataTemplate` is for, you define a DataTemplate for your ToolButton class and now WPF knows how to display this one.

Unfortunately there is another problem in your Button `Template`. Button is of type `ContentControl`, thus allowing it to show any content. You already used the `Content` property. But you are completely overriding the ControlTemplate, remember that a ControlTemplate defines how a control will look like, without its template it shows absolutely nothing. 
Now looking at your template i miss a specialized control called `ContentPresenter` this tells the template "When the button has a content, place it here" so the ContentPresenter is a place holder for the actual set Content. Now remember what i said about the `DataTemplate` and you will see how these things work together.

Another tiny thing is, you use Bindings in your Template, but you never set the DataContext you just set the content, but the content is only valid inside the ContentPresenter, or better, your DataTemplate. There are a couple of "rules" around DataContext. Quick summarize: DataContext can be inherited and is automatically set in a `DataTemplate`.

I hope this helps you abit.
cheers.

Comment: You shouldn't set the template explicitly, since there's  TargetType="{x:Type Button}", which will set this template to each button used

Comment: If type like that it will apply to single button not all button.

Comment: @Amittai Shapira Considering you commented my post i guess you meant me. Because i don't understand exactly what you mean. You can set the template explicitly or implicitly, thats what i said in the first part of my answer. Because the thread starter used a Name in his template i wanted to point out that his ControlTemplate must be set explicitly on each Button where he wants to use this Template. The TargetType has nothing to do with implicit or explicit lookup of the Template, this is decided via the name.